# Remote GraphicsEnvironment Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, remoting

The API from Java seems to indicate that it is possible to have a GraphicsEnvironment that is running in a separate machine:

> The resources in this GraphicsEnvironment might be local or on a remote machine. GraphicsDevice objects can be screens, printers or image buffers and are the destination of Graphics2D drawing methods.

This seems to indicate that it is possible to run a Java Application in one computer but display the screen completely in another computer.

Now, I've not found if this is possible in the internet.  If this is possible, how can it be made?  How can I draw into a separate computer?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that Java has this facility directly.  The note in the documentation refers to the fact that the underlying operating system might support some facility that allows the graphics environment to be remote from the machine actually running the application.  For example, linux systems allow you to "ssh -X" to another machine and run GUI applications.  The application itself is running on the remote machine, but the GUI display is on the local machine.

Comment: +1 This typically works on Mac OS X, Solaris and other Unix flavors, too.

Comment: How can I take advantage of this functionality?